# Synchronized Data Extensions in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

I have created a synchronized data extension which is pulling data from the leads object.

I want to use the same data extension in Journey builder but I am not getting the option to use synchronized data extensions.

Comment: How would you like to "use" this Data Extension in Journey Builder? Do you want to use Attributes (field values) from the Data Extension in an email or SMS?

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding you can not reference a synchronized data extension directly to be used as an entry event in a Journey.

You must create an SQL activity that outputs the relevant data from the lead object to a sendable data extension to be used in a journey.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, using a [Salesforce Data Event](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/using_the_salesforce_sales_and_service_cloud_event/) as your entry event might be what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The synchronized DE is not meant to be used as an audience for the Journey. These are reference data extensions that allow CRM data to be used in decision splits.

If you need to inject contacts into the journey based on CRM data events then Salesforce Data event would be the right approach.

If you need to use CRM data along with some other data available in Marketing Cloud then you'd want to use SQL activity to put together target audience that is then injected into the journey as Eliot mentioned.